# Unable to transfer files via bluetooth between a Samsung Corby TXT and laptop

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth

I successfully paired my laptop & my phone. When I try to send any file from my laptop to my phone via bluetooth, I am getting this message in Ubuntu 11.10:

> Permission Denied(13)

I am also not able to send any data from my phone to laptop via bluetooth!

Also I want to mention that:

In Ubuntu 11.04, I used to send data *from* my laptop to phone via bluetooth but *was not* able to send any data from my phone to laptop via bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Terminal and type

```
hcitool scan
```

appears scan...

```
getting your device mac  address
5F:0J:F6:D9:0C
```

type in terminal

```
sdptool browse xx:xx:xx:xx:xx(your device mac address)
sudo rfcomm connect 0 xx:xx:xx:xx 1
```

Now transfer files bluetooth to your laptop.